# Native Singletons on android platform?

Tags: android-ndk, singleton

My native C++ project I've to port to android platform is based on several static and dynamic libraries, using c++11 based thread safe singletons,
which are shared between those modules.

Here is an example of my actual structure:

```
  brCore  (Core elements, Manager (Singletons), Logger (Singleton) ect.)  STATIC
  brGrapics (Generic graphics) uses brCore STATIC
  brOpenGLES (GLES renderer) uses brCore, brGraphics DYNAMIC
```

My Android Application (also DYNAMIC) uses those three libraries and loads brOpenGLES dynamically on startup.
On Linux and Windows platform anything is working fine, but on android, I got trouble with the Singletons:

```
04-08 06:47:24.601: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called
04-08 06:47:24.611: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Singleton constructor invoked : brFileHandler 
04-08 06:47:24.611: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brFileHandler set internal data path: /data/data/com.binrev/files
04-08 06:47:24.611: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called

04-08 06:47:24.031: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Try to initialize Render API
04-08 06:47:24.031: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called
04-08 06:47:24.051: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Singleton constructor invoked : brRessourceManager
04-08 06:47:24.051: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called

04-08 06:47:24.251: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Try to init Logger: brCore
04-08 06:47:24.251: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Search for existing logger
04-08 06:47:24.282: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called
04-08 06:47:24.282: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Singleton constructor invoked : brRessourceManager

04-08 06:47:24.282: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called
04-08 06:47:24.282: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Singleton constructor invoked : brConfigManager

04-08 06:47:24.601: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called
04-08 06:47:24.611: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): Singleton constructor invoked : brFileHandler
04-08 06:47:24.611: I/NativeActivitySimpleExample(1059): brSingleton getInstance called
```

As you can see, the constructor of the thread safe singletons is called multiple times, what not should be. Values set at the Singleton (brFileHandler internal data path)
are lost at later points. It looks like the libraries have separate instances of the singletons and could not share content among library boundaries...

How could I solve this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I've to use dynamic library instances of my modules.